Array become incomplete under pointerInput
The sorteditem array is directly passed from MainActivity. I added debug println to see if sortedItem array is consistent and I found the sortedItem array under pointerInput will become incomplete. For say, I add a task "banana" (its date is before apple, so it will be placed before it) to the screen with the existing task "apple". And I double-tapped "banana" the sortedItem array will be printed out, showing [apple] but it should be [banana, apple].
@Composable
fun TimelineItem(
    isLast: Boolean,
    date: String,
    day: String,
    strokeWidth: Dp = 8.dp,
    borderWidth: Dp = 1.dp,
    sortedItem:  List<Pair<String, TaskItem>>,
    taskList: List<Pair<String, TaskItem>>
) {
    val lastTapTime = remember { mutableStateOf(0L) }
    val selectedRingId = remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }
    val context = LocalContext.current

    fun navigateToSheet3Activity(description: String) {
        val intent = Intent(context, com.example.mainscreen.ui.Sheet3Activity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("TASK_DESCRIPTION", description)
        }
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }




    // Define handleDoubleTap as a regular function
    fun handleDoubleTap(taskItem: TaskItem, sortedItem: List<Pair<String, TaskItem>>) {
        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (currentTime - lastTapTime.value < 300) {
            // Debugging sortedItem
            println("sorteditem in handleDoubleTap: $sortedItem")

            // Double-tap detected
            val sortedIndex = sortedItem.indexOfFirst { it.second.id == taskItem.id }
            println("sortedIndex: $sortedIndex")

            if (sortedIndex != -1) {
                val fetchedItem = sortedItem[sortedIndex].second
                println("fetchedItem: $fetchedItem")

                navigateToSheet3Activity(fetchedItem.description)
            }
        } else {
            if (selectedRingId.value == taskItem.id) {
                selectedRingId.value = null
            } else {
                selectedRingId.value = taskItem.id
            }
        }
        lastTapTime.value = currentTime
    }


    // Debugging sortedItem state
    LaunchedEffect(sortedItem) {
        println("sortedItem in LaunchedEffect: $sortedItem")
    }

    println("sorteditem on timelineitem " + "$sortedItem")

    println("sorteditem[0] " + sortedItem[0])


    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(20.dp))

        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.size(120.dp)
            ) {
                taskList.forEachIndexed { index, (_, taskItem) ->
                    val ringSize = 120.dp - (index * 17).dp
                    val isSelected = selectedRingId.value == taskItem.id
                    val ringStrokeWidth = if (isSelected) 12.dp else strokeWidth
                    val ringBorderWidth = if (isSelected) 4.dp else borderWidth

                    PercentageRing(
                        date = if (index == 0) date else "",
                        day = if (index == 0) day else "",
                        currentValue = taskItem.currentValue ?: 0,
                        totalValue = taskItem.totalValue,
                        indicatorColor = taskItem.color,
                        ringColor = Color.Gray,
                        strokeWidth = ringStrokeWidth,
                        borderWidth = ringBorderWidth,
                        progress = Float,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(ringSize)
                            .align(Alignment.Center)
                            .clickable {
                                if (selectedRingId.value == taskItem.id) {
                                    selectedRingId.value = null
                                } else {
                                    selectedRingId.value = taskItem.id
                                }
                            }
                    )
                }
            }

            if (!isLast) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(2.dp)
                        .height(40.dp)
                        .background(Color.Black)
                )
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(26.dp))

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .weight(1f)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
            ) {
                if (taskList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    taskList.forEachIndexed { index, (taskDescription, taskItem) ->
                        val topPadding = if (index == 0) 0.dp else 20.dp

                        println("sorteditem on timelineitem 2 " + "$sortedItem")

                        Text(
                            text = "${taskItem.description} - ${taskItem.percentage.toInt()}%",
                            style = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 18.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                            ),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(top = topPadding)
                                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                                .let { textModifier ->
                                    if (taskItem.notificationsEnabled) {
                                        textModifier
                                            .background(
                                                color = Color.Yellow.copy(alpha = 0.2f),
                                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
                                            )
                                            .padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
                                    } else {
                                        textModifier
                                    }


                                }

                                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                                    //println("sorteditem on timelineitem 3 " + "$sortedItem")

                                    detectTapGestures(
                                        onTap = { _ ->
                                            /*
                                            val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                                            if (currentTime - lastTapTime < 300) {

                                                println("sorteditem on timelineitem 3 " + "$sortedItem")
                                                // Double-tap detected
                                                val sortedIndex = sortedItem.indexOfFirst { it.second.id == taskItem.id }

                                                println("sortedIndex " + sortedIndex)

                                                if (sortedIndex != -1) {
                                                    // Fetch the correct data from sortedItemList
                                                    val fetchedItem = sortedItem[sortedIndex].second
                                                    println("fetchItem " + fetchedItem)

                                                    navigateToSheet3Activity(fetchedItem.description)
                                                }

                                            } else {
                                                if (selectedRingId.value == taskItem.id) {
                                                    selectedRingId.value = null
                                                } else {
                                                    selectedRingId.value = taskItem.id
                                                }
                                            }
                                            // Update last tap time
                                            lastTapTime = currentTime */
                                            println("Before Tap - sorteditem: $sortedItem") 

                                            handleDoubleTap(taskItem, sortedItem)

                                            println("After Tap - sorteditem: $sortedItem") 
                                        }
                                    )
                                }
                        )

                        Text(
                            text = "${taskItem.startDate} ~ ${taskItem.endDate}",
                            style = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 10.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal
                            ),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(top = 6.dp)
                                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I created a function "handleDoubleTap" to simplify pointerInput to see if it will reduce the side effects. Also, I added several debug println and pretty sure the sortedItem array will only become incomplete under pointerInput.

Just change the Unit in pointerInput to sortedItem

Could you please explain why
